# How to avoid blocking while using reader.readLine() and sc.nextLine()

Tags: java, sockets, blocking

I am using `reader.readLine()` and `sc.nextLine()` to simulate the server and client. However, after I typed some words in the scanner, the server responded nothing. I think the problem is thread blocking, but I can't correct it. Could any one help point out where the sticking point is.

Here is the code for server.

```
public class Server {

    public static LocalDateTime currentTime() {
        return LocalDateTime.now();
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        ServerSocket ss = new ServerSocket(9091);
        System.out.println("TCP server ready.\n");
        Socket sock = ss.accept();
        try (BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(sock.getInputStream(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8))) {
            try (BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(
                    new OutputStreamWriter(sock.getOutputStream(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8))) {
                String cmd;
                System.out.println("read in");
                while ((cmd = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    System.out.println("Rcvd: " + cmd);
                    if ("time".equals(cmd)) {
                        writer.write(currentTime() + "\n");
                        writer.flush();
                    } else {
                        writer.write("Sorry?\n");
                        writer.flush();
                    }   
                }    
            }
        }
        sock.close();
        ss.close();

    }

}
```

The code for client

```
public class Client {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        InetAddress addr = InetAddress.getLoopbackAddress();
        try (Socket sock = new Socket(addr, 9091)){
            try (BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
                    new InputStreamReader(sock.getInputStream(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8))){
                try (BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(
                        new OutputStreamWriter(sock.getOutputStream(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8))){
                    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
                    String cmd;
                    while (sc.hasNext()) {
                        cmd = sc.nextLine();
                        System.out.println("Scanned: " + cmd);
                        writer.write(cmd);
                        writer.flush();

                        String resp = reader.readLine();
                        System.out.println("Response: " + resp);
                    }

                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: This is probably where you introduce yourself to `Threads` and/or `Concurrency`.

Comment: The server reads the command using readLine (`cmd = reader.readLine()`), the client however does not send a newline after the command (`writer.write(cmd); writer.flush();`), so the server is still waiting for a "\n" from the client before proceeding.

Comment: @Sedrick, thanks for your recommendation. The next step is to use Threads pool/Concurrency.

Answer (score 1):

Use this in Client:

```
writer.write(cmd + "\n");
```

since the server read lines.

Comment: You are right. The `sc.nextLine()` will trim the "\". It works after I append the "\n".

Comment: my typo, "\" is "\n"